# Initializing a "main" iOS image in app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, photos

How would I go about initializing an image to become a sort of "main" image through setting it via button that would be located on each said image? Basically there would be several images, each with a button, but only one could be set as the "main" image, so every time the app is loaded, it would always load to the set main image? Note that I'm still pretty fresh to iOS developing so any tutorials or references would be of great help!

Comment: When you say "every time the app is loaded, it would always load to the set main image", do you mean that each image have their own view, or that in a group of images(all with buttons), the previously selected one has a "selected"-button? You should go a bit more technical with your question as to what the problem is.. Why is there a 'main' image, and how should it act different than the other images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the an apps startup image cannot be changed programmatically - only in the 'Deployment Info' section of projects summary (manually). You can, however have a view that contains an image (which can be changed programmatically) to load after startup, and after a specified delay using either `NSTimer` or `[self performSelector: withObject: afterDelay: ]`. After this, the view can move on to the main part of the application. You can make the user choose a default image in the settings, and keep it as the one that loads in the view after startup by using `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: That sounds perfect! Yeah, I realized each view could have an image that can be set as the default, but you explained it perfectly, thank you so much!